# Flash Element on Event

Tags: javascript, css, animation, innerhtml, pusher

I am subscribed to an API that returns a count (Pusher).

Every time that count increments, I'd like the element whose innerHTML it is pushing the count to, to change color for 1 second and return to its initial state.

```
<h1 id="count"></h1>
```

Is this animation easiest and cleanest done with CSS or javascript?

How is a simple red 1 second flash/blink implemented?

Comment: toggle a class in callback of notification code, use setTimeout() to remove it

Comment: @charlietfl Can you write that up as an answer so I can give you some points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to
toggle a class in callback of notification code, then use `setTimeout()` to remove the class

Comment: thk u sir @charlietfl